# EPartService findpart is null

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, zest

I am trying to get findpart from an ID from e4xmi file. But it is always null. Did I miss anything here. I am new to zest.

```java
package handler;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;
import analysis.ProjectAnalyzer;
import view.View;
public class ASTZestHandler {
private static final String SIMPLEZESTVIEW = 
  "simplezestproject4.partdescriptor.simplezestview4";  

@Execute
public void execute(EPartService service){  
    MPart findPart = service.findPart(SIMPLEZESTVIEW); // it is always null 
    Collection mpart = service.getParts();
    if (findPart != null && findPart.getObject() instanceof View) {
        new ProjectAnalyzer().analyze();
        ((View) findPart.getObject()).update();
    }
}
}
```

My e4xmi code. I have tried all other Id's in my e4xmi code but no matter I use any element id, find part is always null

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
   <fragment:ModelFragments xmi:version="2.0"       xmlns:xmi=
   "http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:basic
 ="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/descriptor/basic"            xmlns: commands
 ="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/commands"          xmlns:fragment
 ="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/fragment"    xmlns:menu="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/menu"    xmi:id="_oDqLAL46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ">
 <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment"   xmi:id="_qS0xQL46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" featurename="descriptors"   parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
 <elements xsi:type="basic:PartDescriptor" xmi:id="_x0-UEL46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" elementId="simplezestproject4.partdescriptor.simplezestview4" label="Simple Zest View 4" iconURI="platform:/plugin/simpleZestProject4/icons/sample.png" contributionURI="bundleclass://simpleZestProject4/view.View"/>
 </fragments>
 <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_q08m4L46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" featurename="commands" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
 <elements xsi:type="commands:Command" xmi:id="_2gK34L46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" elementId="simplezestproject4.command.viewastnodes" commandName="View AST Nodes"/>
 </fragments>
 <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment"   xmi:id="_rRyT4L46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" featurename="handlers" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
 <elements xsi:type="commands:Handler" xmi:id="_7WE24L46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" elementId="simplezestproject4.handler.0" contributionURI="bundleclass://simpleZestProject4/handler.ASTZestHandler" command="_2gK34L46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ"/>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_r6cPUL46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" featurename="menuContributions" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
  <elements xsi:type="menu:MenuContribution" xmi:id="_DithIL47EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" elementId="simplezestproject4.menucontribution.0" positionInParent="after=window" parentId="org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
  <children xsi:type="menu:Menu" xmi:id="_A_CqgL47EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" elementId="simplezestproject4.menu.mymenu" label="My Menu">
    <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem"  xmi:id="_HmhU0L47EeWS1vppwIGIuQ" elementId="simplezestproject4.handledmenuitem.item-showastnodes" label="Item - Show AST Nodes" command="_2gK34L46EeWS1vppwIGIuQ"/>
    </children>
   </elements>
   </fragments>
   </fragment:ModelFragments>
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve? Instantiate a new part based on your PartDescriptor or find a live instance of your PartDescriptor?

If your want to create an instance based on your PartDescriptor, you can do it like this (with `EPartService partService`) :

```java
MPart part = partService.createPart(SIMPLEZESTVIEW);
part.setLabel(...);
part.setElementId(<partname>);
partService.showPart(part, PartState.CREATE);
partService.activate(part, true);
```

If you want to find an instance of a part previously created, use the EModelSrevice like this (with `Application app, EModelService modelService`):

```java
 MPart part = (MPart) modelService.find(<partname>, app);
 if (part !=null) {
    partService.showPart(part, PartState.CREATE);
    partService.activate(part, true);
 }
```

Comment: You can use `EPartService.findPart` to find an existing Part, you don't need to use the model service.

Comment: Right. but a "PartDescriptor" is not a "Part". A "Part" instance is created from a "PartDescriptor". In the initial question, `MPart findPart = service.findPart(SIMPLEZESTVIEW)` is wrong because `SIMPLEZESTVIEW` does not point to a part name, so the hypothesis in my answer